# Configuration of a transfer of data between different database servers (synchronous mode)

Tags: java, database, spring

I have two applications (Java EE Spring) that need to communicate. One is hosted in an extranet and the other is hosted in an intranet.

How can I transfer data between their database servers?  **(synchronous mode)** Should I use a specific script?

Comment: Between "database servers" or "application servers"?

Comment: No I'm talking about database servers

Comment: Each application communicate with it own database server, and one is located in an extranet, the other in an intranet..

Comment: which DBMS you have??